# DELETE rows with specific common column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, the table `sessions` has columns `id` (PK), `user_id` and `expire`. I would like to delete rows with `id = 'deleteme'` but also expired sessions from the same person, namely whose `user_id` match the deleted row and `expire < now()`.

The query that I found to be working is

```
WITH temp AS (
  DELETE FROM sessions 
  WHERE id = 'deleteme' 
  RETURNING user_id)
DELETE FROM sessions 
WHERE user_id IN (
 SELECT user_id from temp)
AND expire < now()
```

What did not work was

```
WITH temp AS (
  DELETE FROM sessions 
  WHERE id = 'deleteme'
  RETURNING user_id)
DELETE FROM sessions
WHERE user_id = temp.user_id
AND expire < now()
```

which has error "missing FROM-clause entry for table 'temp'"

Are there simpler queries that achieve the same effect as my first query?

EDIT: if there are ways to do this with joins please let me know as well for I am quite new to SQL and eager to learn. I just don't know if that will delete from the original table in addition to the joined table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the error message is not exactly clear.

For delete queries you need to have a `USING` clause for your CTE.

So:

```
WITH temp AS (
  DELETE FROM sessions 
  WHERE id = 'deleteme'
  RETURNING user_id)
DELETE FROM sessions
USING temp
WHERE user_id = temp.user_id
AND expire < now()
```

Comment: it says i should do `WHERE sessions.user_id = temp.user_id` or rename `user_id` to avoid ambiguity. So other than that, this works! Could you kindly clarify when is `USING` needed? Looking it up `EQUIJOIN` and `NATURAL JOIN` popped up, both of which I am hearing for the first time.

Comment: USING is needed when referencing a relation you aren't deleting from in a DELETE.